# How to add row dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with one row and two columns (one textbox and button):

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 1;
  
  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;
    $('#dyn').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td><td><button type="button" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger remove">x</button></td></tr>');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row' + i + '').remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <table id="dyn">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="submit"></button>
```

What I want to do is to add new rows to the table and remove them. The problem is when I try to remove one of these rows I am able to remove just one The others stays. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$('#row'+id).remove();`  ?

Comment: _“What am i doing wrong here”_ - you’re relying on ids for element selection more than necessary to begin with …? Your remove button already is inside the row that you want to remove, so no need for ids _at all_ in that regard, you can simply navigate from the button up to the _parent_ tr element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant ID over here instead of i

```
$(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    $('#row'+id+'').remove();
})
```

Comment: I feel very bad   :))))

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the value of `i` will only ever reference the last added row, so when you first click remove the last row will be removed, even if that wasn't the row you clicked to delete. Then on second click the row won't exist any more so nothing appears to happen.

A better approach is to use DOM traversal to find the parent `tr` to the clicked `button`, then remove that. To do this, you can use `closest()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $('#dyn').append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove">x</button></td></tr>');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <table id="dyn">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this

`$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;

    $('#dyn').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td><input type="text" name="name[]"></td><td><button type="button" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger remove">x</button></td></tr>');

  });
  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <table id="dyn">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="submit"></button>
```

Comment: Don't chain `parent()` calls. You're just asking to have your code broken by a basic HTML change. Use `closest()`